# How to fix windows 10 so I can turn it off normally without hard shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

When I want to shutdown windows 10 (Version 22H2, Build 19045.3693), I always get the message

```
Getting Windows ready. Don't turn off your computer
```

so I have to turn it off by pressing the power button.
How can I fix this? Maybe I can try to run a command?

- How long have you waited?  about 40 minutes
- How long as this been going on? started today 27 Nov 2023
- What events happened before this began? Nothing unusual
- Have you checked the Event Viewer to see what might be trying to install? No. I do not know how to use the event viewer
- What have you tried so far? Turning it on and off, running command  `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup` which also resulted in an error: `Error: 0x800f0806  The operation could not be completed due to pending operations.`
- What is the status now? I see a message `Some update files are missing or have problems. We'll try to download the update again later. Error code: (0x80070003)` in "Windows Update". Not sure what I have to do here

Comment: Maybe you should wait for the updates to install?

Comment: Try running  ....    shutdown  /s  ...  after you have checked for and run updates. Updates should be done first...  Also run DISM  / SFC  ....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: How long? 1 hour? 1 day? 1 week? 20 years? When to stop waiting?

Comment: I would set up and allow it to run overnight shutting down.

Comment: On occasion, an update may not complete. First try the Windows Update Troubleshooter, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-troubleshooter-19bc41ca-ad72-ae67-af3c-89ce169755dd. If that doesn't fix the issue, reinstall Windows 10 -- which will be beyond EOL in a year, so consider another OS.

Comment: So I run these `DISM` commands also over night I guess. Seems I cannot do any work for the rest of the week ...

Comment: @John LOL: `Error: 0x800f0806

The operation could not be completed due to pending operations.`

Comment: Feature updates are the ones that take longer but never more than a couple of hours, worst case scenario. Keeping it updated is strongly advised. If you don't like the way Windows handles this situations the solution is simple: **Use Linux**. If you want to keep Windows then you should aware that what you're can only make it worse and not booting at all is not unheard of.

Comment: I AM using Linux but for some tasks I still have to use windows.

Comment: Your question lacks information. How long have you waited? How long as this been going on? What events happened before this began? Have you checked the Event Viewer to see what might be trying to install? What have you tried so far? All this information needs to be in the body of your question to make it clear.

Comment: @Alex - "which also resulted in an error" - What error? [Edit] your question instead of submitting an unformatted comment.  What build are you running exactly?  This problem can be fixed without reinstalling Windows, if you choose to reinstall Windows, then any hope of assisting with this error will become impossible.

Comment: Instead of downvoting let me know what information you need. Or should I post the dump of the harddrive? I am NOT an absolute windows expert, you know

Comment: I created a ticket with IT, I hope they come back this year. Otherwise windows starts and I can stop it by pressing the power button for long time. So all is good...

Answer (score 1):

My old HP laptop was doing that once. I let it run overnight and what it was doing was updating from Windows 10 21H2 to 22H2. I'd say, click `[Windows]` and `[R]` keys to get the Run dialogue, and type in `winver`. If it says anything other that 22H2 or 23H2, I'd say it's a huge update. You should see a box like this, but it would say Windows 10:
[Photo of the "winver" dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnhFN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have read all the comments and your question.  At this point, since the update is pending and (a) it will not finish and (b) you cannot run other updates, then you should truly reinstall Windows. Make sure (as I posted in a comment) to allow the machine to run overnight to see if updates complete.

(1) Back up the drive (boot with a bootable USB Key or put the drive in a carrier and get the backup on another machine).

(2) Reinstall Windows 10 with the ISO from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.   [Media Creation Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

(3) If the system is new enough and meets Windows 11 Specifications (TPM V2, Secure Boot, UEFI and 4 GB of memory) then upgrade to Windows 11 instead of rebuilding Windows 10.

Windows 11 works fine. I upgraded software as necessary and I adapted to changes that were different to Windows 10

Comment: Maybe the windows 11 update is a good idea. But I heard that some things don't work in windows 11 anymore...

Comment: I have been using Windows 11 for nearly 3 years - first Insider, then new Production machines. It works fine.  I upgraded software as necessary and I adapted to changes that were different to Windows 10.